# CSS select last element among all descendants

Tags: css, css-selectors

Without knowing a structure of html, I would like to select the last element `.foo` inside `.main`. In other words the closest element of class `.foo` to closing tag of `.main`.

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="foo a">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="foo b">
    b
    <div class="foo c">
      c - select only this (last .foo among all descendants)
    </div>
    <div class="d">
      d
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course I can `.main > .foo > .foo` but I want a generic solution.

Comment: cannot be done with css

Comment: Worth adding though, that even though this cannot be done with css alone, it's relatively straightfoward to achieve with js and css: `let allFooInMain = [... document.querySelectorAll('.main .foo')]; let lastFooInMain = allFooInMain[(allFooInMain.length - 1)]; lastFooInMain.classList.add('last-foo-in-main');` Then you can style `.last-foo-in-main`.